# Windows C++ Lock file in memory

Tags: c++, windows, caching, filesystems, fread

If I need to read from a file very often, and I will load the file into a vector of unsigned char using fread, the consequent fread are really fast, even if the vector of unsigned char is destroy right after reading.

It seems to me that something (Windows or the disk) caches the file and thus freads are very fast. I have not read anything about this behaviour, so I am unsure what really causes this.

If I don't use my application for 1 hour or so and then do an fread again, the fread is slow.
It seems to me that the cache got emptied.

Can somebody explain this behaviour to me? I would like to actively use it. 
It is a problem for me when the freads are slow.

Memory-mapping the file works theoretically, but the file itself is too big, so I can not use it.

Comment: Windows has a disk cache, and it works quite nicely. Expecting Windows to keep your data around in that cache for hours/days is not exactly all that friendly. What makes YOUR data so much more important than the data of anything ELSE on the system?

Comment: I need to perform the freads quickly, therefore I was trying to find a way to tell Windows that the file is important to me and I need to access it often and quickly.

Comment: just read it... it'll get cached. as long as you keep reading it, windows should keep it cached. you'd only hit the slow read ONCE after it gets booted from the cache.

Comment: If memory mapping the file is no option because the file is too big, then there is no way to keep it in RAM either. But there also is no way that the cache would work in your favour. If the pages you need don't fit in RAM (or are bigger than your address space) then they won't fit in the buffer cache either. That said, memory mapping the subranges of the file that you need is pretty much the only way to "force" the OS to keep them around, and even then you're not certain, since you can't lock many megabytes. It's just more likely, not certain. I recommend against such tricks, though.

Answer (score 2):

## 90/10 law

> 90% of the execution time of a computer program is spent executing 10% of the code

It is not a rule but usually it is so, so lots of programs tries to keep recent data if possible because it is very likely that that data will be accessed very soon again.

Windows OS is not an exception, after receiving command to read file OS keeps some data about file. It stores in memory addresses of ages where the program is stored, if possible even store some part (or even all) of binary data in memory, it makes next file read much faster if that read is just after the first-one.

All-in-all you are right that there is caching, but I can't to say, that is really going on as I'm not working in Microsoft...

---

Also answering into next part of question. File mapping into memory may be solution but if the file is very large machine may not have stat much memory so it wouldn't be an option. However, you can use the *90/10 law*. In your case you should have just a part of file mapped into memory (that part that is the most important), also while reading you should make a data table of overall parameters.

Don't know exact situation, but it may save.